# Does integral converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does integral
$$\int \int \int _{R^{3}\setminus{(0,0,0)}} \frac {\cos(4x^2+16y^2+z^2)}{(4x^2+16y^2+z^2)^ \frac {1}{2}} \, dx \, dy \, dz$$
converge?
I tried to check convergence over sets $K_{n}$={$(x,y,z) \in R^{3}  : \frac {1}{n^2} \leq 4x^2+16y^2+z^2 \leq n^{2}$} and then go on eliptical coordinates. My integral become $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\pi}{2}\int _ \frac {1}{n}^{n} \frac{cosr^{2}}{r}dr$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If your question is about whether $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1/n}^n \cos(r^2)/r dr$ converges, the only way that it possibly could is if you somehow chose the rate of the outer radius and inner radius to be scaling just perfectly together to get some cancellation, since the integral at the lower endpoint is diverging. And if you did pick the scaling that way then the overall integral would only converge in a PV sense. But in fact you haven't changed variables correctly, you need the Jacobian to be in there, and with it there you wind up with $r \cos(r^2)$ instead which won't converge.

Comment: Your final integral seems wrong. The volume element in polar coordinates is $r^2 \,\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \Omega$. So you should get $\int_{r > 0} r\cos(r^2)\, \mathrm{d}r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your triple integral $I$ so $x\mapsto 2x,\,y\mapsto 4y$ gives$$I=\frac18\iiint_{\Bbb R^3}\frac{\cos(r^2)}{r}d^3x=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty r\cos(r^2)dr=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\infty\cos(u)du,$$which is undefined.